# Problem in understanding a point in argument-dependent lookup

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I have this simple example to clarify my problem:

```
struct S;

namespace A{
    void f(S&&) {};
    namespace B{
       struct S{};
    }
}

int main(void) {
    f(A::B::S()); 
}
```

This program is ill-formed since it can't find the name `f` by argument-dependent lookup.

But [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) states the following:

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), is the set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to overloaded operators. **These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.**

Per my understanding of the above wording, I see that namespace `A` is looked up by unqualified lookup, so when ADL searches for the function name `f`, the namespace `A` has to be examined in addition to namespace `A::B`. So why ADL does not search for `f` in `A`? Does namespaces `A` is considered by the usual unqualified name lookup? Am I understand the bold part correctly?

Comment: In this case _"...usual unqualified name lookup.."_ will only look in the global namespace.  ADL will consider `A::B`.

Comment: @RichardCritten: _"...usual unqualified name lookup.." will only look in the global namespace._ Let me understand how you came to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

> These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.

- *"These function names"*: `f` in your case.
- *"in the namespaces of their arguments"*: `A::B` in your case as this function (whose name is still to be looked up) is called with an argument whose type is `A::B::S`.
- *"the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup"*: this is the global namespace as well as the "current" namespace.

In conclusion:

```
f(A::B::S());  // wont find A::f
f(::S());      // wont find A::f

namespace N
{
    class C{};
    void g(C) {}
}
g(N::C{});     // will find N::g through ADL via the namespace of g's argument
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by "current" namespace? What is it in my example?

Comment: Here the current namespace is the global namespace. If the definition of `N` and the call of `g` were all in a namespace `N2`, the unqualified lookup would consider both the global namespace and `::N2`.

Comment: Additionally, unqualified lookup also considers the scope of the call (if done in the definition of a class for instance).